# Crop out all mapped area beyond region of 13 U.S. states

Tags: r, crop, mask, tmap

I've just started with mapping in R and I've managed to convert a lat, lon dataframe to a raster file and then plot state borders on top of that.

[image]

Now I need to get it ready to publish and would like to include only the shape of my 13-state region (and no great lakes).

```
library(tmap)    

usa <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE))

map_us<- tm_shape(usa)+
    tm_borders()  

tm_shape(raster_file) + 
  tm_raster(style = "cont", palette = "viridis", midpoint = 0)+
  map_us
```

I'm having a hard time finding something out there that would provide a polygon for multiple states and I have been through a lot of mapping packages. Sorry I can't include my raster data here.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want great lakes to be excluded from `map_us`, right?

Comment: Yes! Just North Dakota, South Dakota, Nebraska, Kansas, Missouri, Iowa, Minnesota, Wisconsin, Illinois, Indiana, Ohio, Wisconsin, and Michigan. No lakes.

Comment: Well it's not that easy. I don't think there's a raster out there with waterbodies excluded from the map. you need to exclude them manually. That's what I think tho, maybe someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To crop a raster file to {sf} vector shape you have in principle two options:

- crop at data level; this involves `raster::mask()` with possibly `raster::crop()` later to reduce the extent of the raster (masked raster retains the original size)
- retain the data, and overlay a white polygon with a hole over your plot

Cropping on data level is more "pure", but will leave you with ragged edges (a raster cell *has* to be square).

Overlaying a white polygon is not so pure, but might be preferable if your key aim is a slick presentation (and purity of essence be damned...)

You will find both of them discussed, together with examples and sample code, in [this post on the RStudio community site](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-crop-gridded-data-with-shapefile/40323/8?u=jlacko).